# Need help in positioning two views in LinearLayout dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

activity_checklist_detail.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChecklistDetail">
    
    <include
        android:id="@+id/include4"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include4"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is ChecklistDetail activity

```
 public class ChecklistDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist_detail);

        toolbar= findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int id = intent.getIntExtra("id",0);
        String status = intent.getStringExtra("status");
        String content = intent.getStringExtra("content");


        String[] statusSplit = status.split("\n");
        String[] contentSplit = content.split("\n");
        int i=0;
        for ( i = 0; i < contentSplit.length; i++) {
            
            final int j = i;

            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            
            boolean state;

            if(statusSplit[i].equals("1"))
                state=true;
            else
                state=false;

           
            editText.setText(contentSplit[i]);
            checkBox.setChecked(state);

            SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(editText.getText().toString());
            StrikethroughSpan strikethroughSpan = new StrikethroughSpan();
            spannableString.setSpan(strikethroughSpan,0, checkBox.getText().length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            if(checkBox.isChecked()) {
                editText.setText(spannableString);
            }

            linearLayout.addView(checkBox);
            linearLayout.addView(editText);
            

            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(editText.getText().toString());
                    StrikethroughSpan strikethroughSpan = new StrikethroughSpan();
                    spannableString.setSpan(strikethroughSpan,0, editText.getText().length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    if(checkBox.isChecked()) {
                        editText.setText(spannableString);
                    }
                    else {
                        editText.setText(contentSplit[j]);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.edit_save_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    }
```

I want to get the views like image below.
[image]

but nothing works for me. If I change the layout in activity_checklist_detail to horizontal or vertical I'll get as the image below.

If I set to horizontal, I'll get [image]

If I change to vertical, I'll get like this below
[image]

Note: I know that using RecyclerView is the best option, but here I don't have many items.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of direct adding a view to your layout better to create a separate layout and add it into your `LinearLayout` like this

> Create a separate layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

  <CheckBox
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/edt_name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

> Add view in your linearlayout like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    for (i in 0..5) {
      val layoutBinding = TaskOneBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
      layoutBinding.edtName.hint = "position $i"
      binding.linearLayout.addView(layoutBinding.root)
    }
  }
}
```

> Java code

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ActivityMainBinding mainBinding;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(mainBinding.getRoot());

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      TaskOneBinding taskOneBinding = TaskOneBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
      taskOneBinding.edtName.setHint("position " + i);
      mainBinding.linearLayout.addView(taskOneBinding.getRoot());
    }
  }
}
```

> OUTPUT

[image]